# adding permissions to an object which is not an instance of Django User in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added a Meta class which contains the following permissions but i don't know if its added just by only putting them in Meta class or i need to add something or assign them by a certain way. Here is my code :

```
class Contractor(models.Model): 
    contractor_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    Employer = models.OneToOneField(Employer)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
        ("permission", "perm"),
        ("bid", "bid"),
        ("send_request_to_verifier", "send_request_to_verifier"),
        ("gain_points", "gain_points"),
        ("loose_points", "loose_points"),
        )
```

and i am sorry if anything is not clear. I just need help on how to add custom permissions to an object which is not an instance of Django User

Comment: You are doing it correctly. You add permissions to objects, allowing and disallowing access to those objects for django Users. Are you saying that you don't use the User system at all?

Comment: Yes i mean that the Contractor is a Model not an instance of Django User so when i try to use cont = Contractor.objects.get(id=1) then
cont.user_permissions.add('appname.permission') it gives me an error because ofcoarse this methods is bult in in Django user so what i want to know is how to add the permissions without the built in django user methods just for Models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The django permissions system is only designed out of the box to support User and Group model permissions. From the django docs regarding object permissions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#handling-object-permissions

> Django's permission framework has a foundation for object permissions,
>   though there is no implementation for it in the core. That means that
>   checking for object permissions will always return False or an empty
>   list (depending on the check performed).

If you are looking for generic object-level permissions, there are a slew of available packages here:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=django+permissions&submit=search

Some of these simply implement the model level permissions, and some let you define a per instance permission.